# paperclip - test if images have been uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have 2 models (Book & Image)

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :images

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

end 




class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :book

    has_attached_file :data, :path => ":rails_root/public/system/datas/:book_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                      :url => "/system/datas/:book_id/:style/:basename.:extension",


    :styles => {
      :thumb => ["150x172#",:jpg],
      :large => ["100%", :jpg]
    }

  validates_attachment_presence :data
    validates_attachment_content_type :data,
    :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg',
                    'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/tiff', 'image/gif'], :message => "has to be in a proper format"



end
```

I would like to modify my application so that when users create a new book and uploads an image, they’re redirected to a specific page, otherwise they are directed to the 'Show' page

I have modified my 'create' action in the Book Controller as follows:

```
def create
    @book = Book.new(params[:book])


    if @book.save

      flash[:notice] = 'Book was successfully created'

      if params[:book][:image][:data].blank?  # === this line is giving me errors
        redirect_to @specific_page
      else  
         redirect_to show_book_path(@book.id)
      end

    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end

  end
```

I want to test that if an image or multiple images have been uploaded, user should be directed to a different page

The following if condition is erroneous:

```
if params[:book][:image][:data].blank?  # === this line is giving me errors
```

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest me how to to check if images have been attached to the new Book.

Please note that I want to check for only newly uploaded images, not all images associated with the book.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am not sure about your view file. But if user has not selected/uploaded a single image, then params[:book][:image] will be nil and thus 'if params[:book][:image][:data].blank?' line give error.

Try checking the 'image' instances associated with book instance

```
if @book.images.any?
  redirect_to @specific_page
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I want to check for only newly uploaded images, not all images associated with the book. '@book.images.any?
' is checking for all images associated with the book

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ruby's `FileTest` Module. There's an `exists?` method which returns true if the given file exists, or false otherwise.

See API documentation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/FileTest.html#method-i-exists-3F).